# Tomcat configuration using embedded ActiveMQ JMS

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, configuration, activemq-classic

I have Tomcat 7.0.42 and ActiveMQ 5.10 and have added the following resources to my context.xml file:

```
<Resource 
    auth="Container" 
    brokerName="MyActiveMQBrokerXML" 
    description="JMS Connection Factory" 
    factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory" 
    name="jms/ConnectionFactory" 
    type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" 
    useEmbeddedBroker="true"
    brokerURL="vm://localhost?brokerConfig=xbean:activemq.xml"
    />
```

When starting Tomcat via is built-in startup script I get the following in the console out-put.

```
2015-01-27 09:49:24,064 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl- PListStore:[C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\bin\acti vemq-data\MyActiveMQBroker\tmp_storage] started 
2015-01-27 09:49:24,068 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService- Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[C:\tomcat\ap ache-tomcat-7.0.57\bin\activemq-data\MyActiveMQBroker\KahaDB]   
2015-01-27 09:49:24,471 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase- KahaDB is version 5 
2015-01-27 09:49:24,491 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase- Recovering from the journal ... 
2015-01-27 09:49:24,492 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase- Recovery replayed 3 operations from the journal in 0.01 seconds. 
2015-01-27 09:49:24,663 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService- Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 (MyActiveMQBroker, ID:Jacob-PC-55865-1422 373764525-0:1) is starting 
2015-01-27 09:49:24,707 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector- Connector vm://localhost?brokerConfig=xbean:activemq.xml st arted 
2015-01-27 09:49:24,707 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService- Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0 (MyActiveMQBroker, ID:Jacob-PC-55865-1422 373764525-0:1) started 
2015-01-27 09:49:24,708 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService- For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache. org 
2015-01-27 09:49:24,711 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService- Memory Usage for the Broker (1024 mb) is more than the maximum a vailable for the JVM: 247 mb - resetting to 70% of maximum available: 173 mb 
2015-01-27 09:49:24,728 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerRegistry- Broker localhost not started so using MyActiveMQBroker instead Jan 27, 2015 9:49:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

It appears to me that tomcat is not looking for the activemq.xml file or is at least not using it.  This exact configuration works if I start tomcat through eclipse, but that is not a viable option for a production system.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? i'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I found that if deploying into production you have to use the absolute path to the file to get Tomcat to find the activemq.xml file. Although using the relative path is supposed to work, I could never get it to.

```
brokerURL="vm://localhost?brokerConfig=xbean:activemq.xml"
```

Supposedly only works if you've added to 'activemq.xml' to the class path. Note the presence of 'file' in 'xbean:file:/some/path/activemq.xml'.

```
<Resource id="MyJmsResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
        BrokerXmlConfig =  xbean:file:/usr/share/apache-tomee-plus-8.0.0-M1/conf/activemq.xml
        ServerUrl       =  tcp://localhost:61616            
</Resource>
```